# Printing a Webview == Clipped content after changing scaleUnitSquareToSize

Tags: cocoa, printing, webkit

I've used the code below to emulate Safari's ability to change the scale of a webpage:

```
-(IBAction)changeScale:(NSControl *)sender {
    [[[[wv mainFrame] frameView] documentView] setBounds:[self originalBounds]];
    [[[[wv mainFrame] frameView] documentView] scaleUnitSquareToSize:NSMakeSize([sender floatValue], [sender floatValue])];
    [[[[wv mainFrame] frameView] documentView] setNeedsDisplay:YES];
 }
```

The problem I'm having is that when I print after decreasing the scale, while the content is smaller, it isn't repaginating:  A document originally 4 pages long is still 4 pages, but the pages are only partially full.  My expectation is that the pages would be narrower but also use the full height of the paper.

To print, I'm using this:

```
[[[[wv mainFrame] frameView] documentView] print:sender];
```

Thoughts?

Thanks!
Woody

---

Update:
I addressed this issue with the Print team at WWDC and it turns out my implementation wasn't the ideal implementation. ;)  They advised me to not add scale functionality by modifying the webview.  Instead, they suggested I modify the Print Dialog options so it adds the Scale  parameters, allowing it to be adjusted during printing/PDF-making.

Case closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution edited into the original question.